# Filter array object via element in other array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I have an array that looks like

```
const toFilter = [1,4,5]
```

And another array that has a structure like

```
const foo = [{id: 1, time:XXX}, {id:2, time:XXX}, {id: 3, time: XXX}.....]
```

I want to filter out the element in the first arrays from the element with the same id in the second array (for example in the above example the first object with id 1 would be removed as is present in toFilter and fooo would look like `[{id:2, time:XXX}, {id: 3, time: XXX}]`)

My code seems to not be working:

```
const pos = result.data.filter((el) => toFilter.includes(!el.id))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your [negation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) is put in the wrong spot. You want to check if `toFilter` does not include the id, not if it includes the boolean inverse of the id.

```
const pos  result.data.filter((el) => !toFilter.includes(el.id))
```

```js
const toFilter = [1,4,5]
const foo = [{id: 1, time:'XXX'}, {id:2, time:'XXX'}, {id: 3, time: 'XXX'}];
const pos = foo.filter((el) => !toFilter.includes(el.id));
console.log(pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way :

```
let filteredArray = result.data.filter((el) => !toFilter.includes(el.id));
```

Let me know if that works !

Answer (score 0):

```
const toFilter = [1,4,5]

const foo = [{id: 1, time:'asdf'}, {id:2, time:'asdf'}, {id: 3, time: 'asdf'}]

const result = foo.filter(el => !toFilter.includes(el.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have you `!` in the wrong place !.

Try...

```
const pos = result.data.filter((el) => !toFilter.includes(el.id))
```